# Can anyone identify this uniform? Is it from Sweden or USA?

Tags: united-states, identification, uniform, sweden

I have 2 photos of my husband's grandfather Edwin Albin (1884-1962) that were taken in Minnesota in 1906. I’m hoping to find out more about the uniform Albin is wearing.   Albin's father Claus August Swanson (1844–1909) emigrated from Sweden to the USA in 1869. We are not sure if the uniform belonged to Claus and he brought it here from Sweden.
[image: Man in costume]Any help identifying this uniform is great appreciated.

> Claus August Swanson, 1844 - 1909 Claus föddes på dag månad 1844, i födelseort, till Sven Svensson och Johanna Svensson. Sven föddes på 26 juli 1796, i Gustaf Adolf, Skaraborg Johanna föddes på 12 januari 1801, i Habo, Gustaf Adolf, Skaraborg, Claus döptes på dag månad 1844, i dopplats. Han hade 6 syskon: Anna Stina Svensdotter, Carl Gustaf Svensson och 4 andra syskon. Claus gifte sig med Maja Stina Swanson. Maja föddes på 19 maj 1845, i Simmestorp, Travad, Skaraborg, De hade 2 barn: alvin swanson och ett annat barn. Claus avled på dag månad 1909, vid 65 år i döds plats, Minnesota.

Comment: It looks to me more like a theatrical costume than any uniform in use in 1906 by any military service.

Comment: @kimchilover Indeed, but looking at Swiss Guard, let's call it likely a *ceremonial* remnant from pre1700? // Do you know more about the person's inclination towards theatre, military service (is that really the same person in both pics, without any weapons on display?)

Comment: You'd think a military uniform would have some sort of insignia. It might be livery for some noble.

Comment: It is the same person in both photos, In the photo on the left it looks like there is some type of gun holster.

Comment: Partial answer: it is not a USA military uniform.

Comment: @LanglangC The uniform of the Swiss guard is a 20th century design.

Comment: @Jos Yooo, [thing is: some *retro* is the design inspiration, not just 'fantasy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Guard#Uniforms) is the point likely to drive home in answer; similar to carnival uniforms in Cologne. Style is like kimchiaficionado identified non-frontline/non-battledress…

Comment: @LаngLаngС, I can't place the 'uniform'. What I do know is that this guy didn't travel steerage, if he could pack something like that in his trunk. :-)

Comment: From where in Sweden did Claus August emigrate ? For me, Claus is a very much german name, and so:  were he of german descent ? And, no for me that uniform is very much more like a theatrical one than a real swedish or norwegian 1860's uniform !

Comment: Is your Claus August Svenson the same as :https://www.myheritage.se/names/claus_svensson#col_a_10180   I live in Skaraborg, and no i don't recognize the uniform.

Comment: The king Karl XIV Johan's general uniform were much influenced by his Marechal d'Empire uniform. By 1850, the swedish army uniforms were very much modern european ones.

Comment: @djswanson That's more likely to be some silly brocade on the side of the hose rather than a gun holster.

Comment: @djswanson You can use the edit function to update your question with any clarifications. Comments are temporary and may eventually be erased.  I believe you have a typo on the data of death on Albin (working on the assumption [this](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/119712407/edwin-albin-swanson) is your Albin). Can you provide more information on how you know the photo is from 1906? If you have information on the location and or name of the photographic studio (Information on the back possibly?) please add that to your update.

Comment: @ justcal After doing more research and contacting the MN Historical Society we now believe it is a theatrical costume. The photo on the back states it was taken in 1906 at a photo studio in Mpls.
Albin Aka Alvin Edwin Swanson 
B: 8 Aug 1884 in MN - D:29 Jun 1962 in MN

Comment: Yes, thats where I was at on it also. Some of the features seem 16th century, so  not  any active service, even in the 1800s (with the exception of some ceremonial  British Yeoman Guard units.)

Comment: @djswanson - please feel free to answer you own question.

Comment: @djswanson I don't see a gun holster. I guess you're referring to what's on his right leg just above the boot partially concealed by his right hand? That looks like ruffles, same you can see clearly in the right picture on his left leg. It's colorized oddly. A holster would be smooth and rigid, this is crumply and soft.